# 商品追加ボタンを押しても画面に商品が追加されない。

Tags: php

PHPで自動販売機システムを製作しているのですが、
商品の名前、値段、個数、ファイル等商品情報を登録して追加ボタンを押下した後、

[image]

商品一覧に何も表示されません。

[image]

ですが、DBには登録されております。

[image]

どのように画面に表示すればいいかわからない状況です。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

functions.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/index.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/result.php');

$uploaddir = './drink_picture/';
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];

function get_db_connect() {
 
    if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
 
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
 
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {
    
    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
    
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
       
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['new_name'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください';
                    break;
                case ($_POST['new_name'] === NULL);
                    $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください';
                    break;
                default:
                    $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['new_price'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
                    break;
                case ($_POST['new_price'] === NULL):
                    $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
                    break;
                case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST['new_price']) !== 1):
                    $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    break;
                default:
                    $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['new_stock'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = '個数を入力してください';
                    break;
                case ($_POST['new_stock'] === NULL):
                    $err_msg[] = '個数を入力してください';
                    break;
                case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST['new_stock']) !== 1):
                    $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    break;
                default:
                    $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($_FILES['new_img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        

                $chk_picture = getimagesize($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name']);

                if ($chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/png' || $chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {

                    if ($chk_picture[0] <= 500 && ($chk_picture[1] <= 500)) {

                        $mime = $chk_picture['mime'];
                        switch ($mime) {
                            case 'image/png':
                                $type = '.png';
                                break;
                            case 'image/jpeg':
                                $type = '.jpg';
                                break;
                        }

                        
                    } else {
                        $err_msg[] = 'ファイルは縦と横500px以内にしてください';
                    }
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'PNGかJPEG形式のファイルをアップロードしてください';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ファイルを選択してください';
        }


        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
            if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
                $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ステータスを選択してください';
        }


            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $insert_data_info = [
                'drink_name' => $new_name,
                'price' => $new_price,
                'created_at' => $new_time,
                'updated_at' => $new_time,
                'status' => $new_status
            ];
            print_r($insert_data_info);

            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_name, price, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

                $insert_data_stock = [
                    'drink_id' => $drink_id,
                    'stock' => $new_stock,
                    'created_at' => $new_time,
                    'updated_at' => $new_time
                ];

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO stock_table(drink_id, stock, created_at, updated_at) VALUES(\''.$drink_id.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\')';

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
                    $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'drink_info_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
            }
                $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
            }


        
function update_drink() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

        if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
            if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['update_stock'])) === 1) {
                $update_stock = (int) cut($_POST['update_stock']);

                $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

                $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $update_id;

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = '在庫数の更新に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
            }
        }
    }
}
function change_drink() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

        if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
            if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
                $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
                $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

                $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET updated_at = \'' . $change_time . '\', status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($err_msg) === 0) {
        
        mysqli_commit($link);
    } else {
        
        mysqli_rollback($link);
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, stock_table.stock, drink_info_table.status, drink_info_table.path FROM drink_info_table LEFT JOIN stock_table ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
}



function do_sql() {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.path, stock_table.stock
    FROM drink_info_table
    JOIN stock_table
    ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id
    WHERE drink_info_table.status = 1';

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
}

function id_check() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        $purchase_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        if (isset($_POST['drink_id']) === TRUE) {

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['drink_id'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
                    break;
                case ($_POST['drink_id'] === NULL):
                    $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
                    break;
                default:
                    $drink_id = (int) $_POST['drink_id'];
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = '商品を選択してください';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['money']) === TRUE) {

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($_POST['money'] === ''):
                    $err_msg[] = '金額を入力してください';
                    break;
                case ($_POST['money'] === NULL):
                    $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからmoneyを受信できませんでした';
                    break;
                case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['money'])) !== 1):
                    $err_msg[] = '金額は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    break;
                default:
                    $money = (int) cut($_POST['money']);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

            $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.path, drink_info_table.status, stock_table.stock
            FROM drink_info_table
            JOIN stock_table
            ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id
            WHERE drink_info_table.drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = '情報の取得に失敗しました';
            }

            foreach ($data as $info) {

                $drink_name = $info['drink_name'];
                $price = (int) $info['price'];
                $stock = (int) $info['stock'];
                $path = $info['path'];
                $status = (int) $info['status'];

                $remaining_stock = $stock - 1;
                $return = $money - $price;
            }

            switch (TRUE) {
                case ($return < 0):
                    $err_msg[] = 'お金が足りません';
                    break;
                case ($remaining_stock < 0):
                    $err_msg[] = 'この商品は品切れです';
                    break;
                case ($status === 0):
                    $err_msg[] = 'この商品は選択できません';
                    break;
            }

            $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $remaining_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $purchase_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_history_table(drink_id, purchased_at) VALUES (' . $drink_id . ', \'' . $purchase_time . '\')';

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
                    $err_msg[] = 'drink_history_tableへの追加に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableの更新に失敗しました';
            }
            function html_enc($text)
            { 
              return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

tool.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

$data =  [
                'drink_name' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'created_at' => '',
                'updated_at' => '',
                'status' => '',
            ];
$link = get_db_connect();

$data = insert_drink($link);

close_db_connect($link);
```

tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php if (count($complete_msg) !== 0) {
        foreach ($complete_msg as $complete) { ?>
            <p><?php print $complete; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <?php if (count($err_msg) !== 0) {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <input type="file" name="new_img" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" /><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品画像</th>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>

                <?php if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ($data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <td><img class="image" src="<?PHP print $list['path']; ?>"></td>
                            <? php print $list ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print html_enc($list['drink_name']); ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

const.php

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './drink_picture/';
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];

define('DB_HOST',   ''); // データベースのホスト名又はIPアドレス
define('DB_USER',   '');  // MySQLのユーザ名
define('DB_PASSWD', '');    // MySQLのパスワード
define('DB_NAME',   '');    // データベース名

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Comment: 関数`select_drink`は何をしてようとしていますか？中身が変数を宣言しただけで実質は何も書かれていないようですが。。

Comment: コード変更しました。こちらのコードだとDBには接続できており、データを保存できております。ご確認のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「商品一覧が表示されない」と言っている画面は恐らく `tool2.php` のようですが、この中でデータベースを参照するような記述が見当たりません。

Comment: 商品一覧を画面に表示する方法がわからないというとそれはざっくりとした質問の印象です。おそらくは何らかのカリキュラムの課題なのでしょう。となればその講座中に必ず解答やヒントがあるはずです。それをまずは振り返ってみたほうがいいでしょう。

Comment: どう記述すればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

データは取れているようですので、単に表示されていない可能性やどこでエラーになっているのかの切り分けのためhtmlの描画がどこまでできているかで切り分けたほうがいいと思います。Chromeの場合でしたらば、デベロッパーツールで表示された画面に生成されたhtmlソースを見ることができます。

なお、少なくとも以下の`html_enc`のfunctionの記述は入れ子になってしまっており、html側でうまく呼べていないようです。
ですので、この`<td class="d_name"><?php print html_enc($list['drink_name']); ?>`でエラーになっており、以降のhtml出力ができなくなっているように見えるため、直したほうがいいと思います。

こうなっているのを

```php
function id_check() {
 //(略）
    function html_enc($text)
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

こうしたらいかがでしょう。

```php
function id_check() {
 //(略）
}
function html_enc($text)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

使用する変数を宣言します。 エラーが発生しないようにします。